asizeof appears to be inaccurate
Take this MWE:
from pympler import asizeof
from random import randint, choice
from string import printable
from heapq import heappush
ascii =  printable[:-5]
pq = []
for _ in range(10_000_000):
    heappush(pq, (randint(0, 31), randint(0, 31), randint(0, 31), ''.join(choice(ascii) for _ in range(16))))
print(asizeof.asizeof(pq))

I can see from running 'top' that this takes about 2.7GB of RAM. But asizeof reports 1,449,096,184 bytes which is a long way off.
This is what 'top" shows:

/usr/bin/time -v gives:
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2858616

Using another way of measuring RAM:
from resource import getrusage, RUSAGE_SELF
print(getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss * 1024)

This returns
2927054848


"this takes about 2.6GB of RAM" - what's this exactly? It's probably not just the object whose size asizeof measures.

What is the question now? You removed the one that was there, and now there isn't any.

@KellyBundy I think you have answered the question. Thank you.

asizeof rather accurately does what it's supposed to do: Measure the total size of the object structure. That's just not all the memory that Python uses.
I get the exact same total 1,449,096,184 bytes with this minified test (Attempt This Online!):
from sys import getsizeof

def size(obj, align=8):
    return getsizeof(obj) // -align * -align

a = []
for _ in range(10_000_000):
    a.append((0, 0, 0, ' ' * 16))

list_size = size(a)
tuple_size = size(a[0])
str_size = size(a[0][3])
ints_size = sum(map(size, range(32)))

print(f'{
    list_size +
    len(a) * (tuple_size + str_size) +
    ints_size
:,}')

Using align=16 (also in asizeof) would be more realistic, that's likely the alignment your Python uses. I get 1,529,096,192 bytes then.

Why is it 1GB out though and is there a more accurate way to measure memory use in python?

@Simd Sorry, I don't know enough about top and your system's memory management. You could try from resource import * and print(getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss * 1024), but in some testing of mine, that showed barely more than the asizeof result.

Another simple route is to increase the problem size and notice when it runs out of memory.

@Simd Maybe this or its linked duplicate could explain a bit. I think it would also be good if you showed your top output in your question.

I added some memory information

@Simd Since that time command shows "Maximum resident set size", maybe print(getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss * 1024) works for you? What do you get with that?

That outputs 2927054848. The biggest number yet!

@Simd Not quite. In kbytes that's 2858452, slightly smaller than the 2858616 you got with time -v. (The 164 kbytes difference is so small that presumably they use the same measurement and the difference just happens at the end of the program, after the print.)

Very good point.

The memory management in python is implemented based on C's malloc and free. This approach can cause memory fragmentation specially in large data structures like priority queues.
Moreover, top command has 2 main differences with asizeof:

top reports the total memory allocated by your process, including fragmented memory, while asizeof only accounts for the memory directly used by your objects.
top shows both virtual and physical memory usage. Your code might be using a large amount of virtual memory, which is not necessarily backed by physical memory, but asizeof likely only reports the physical memory usage of your objects.


I was reporting only the physical memory from top.
